# Pandas Dataframe CSV export, how to prevent additional double-quote characters

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am using Pandas to process and output data for a table which is published in Wordpress

I am adding HTML code to format color one column

Starting with a sample Dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
                'A': ['group1', 'group2', 'group3'],
                'B': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo'] })
```

print df

```
        A    B
0  group1  foo
1  group2  foo
2  group3  foo
```

I then add the same formatting code to each row like this:

```
df['Status'] = '<span style="color: #00CD00">Active</span>'

print df    

        A    B                                      Status
0  group1  foo  <span style="color: #00CD00">Active</span>
1  group2  foo  <span style="color: #00CD00">Active</span>
2  group3  foo  <span style="color: #00CD00">Active</span>
```

I export the data as a csv file, because I need the comma delimiters:

```
output = r'C:\test\test.csv'
df.to_csv(output, index=False)
```

If I open the csv in Excel, it looks exactly as above

But if I open it in a text editor (which I need to do to get the delimiters), I find the column with the formatting string has additional doublequote characters, like this:

```
"<span style=""color: #00CD00"">Active</span>"
```

-- this is without the added doublequotes -- which would be correct:

```
<span style="color: #00CD00">Active</span>
```

Does anybody know how I can export this without the additional characters?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

References:

- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE

Sample Program:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
df = pd.DataFrame({
                'A': ['group1', 'group2', 'group3'],
                'B': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo'] })
df['Status'] = '<span style="color: #00CD00">Active</span>'
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Result:

```
$ cat test.csv
A,B,Status
group1,foo,<span style="color: #00CD00">Active</span>
group2,foo,<span style="color: #00CD00">Active</span>
group3,foo,<span style="color: #00CD00">Active</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, I already tried that -- it results in that column not being exported at all

Comment: As you can see from my edit, it works for me. Can you a short, complete sample program, along with its output in your question?

Comment: Thanks, Rob. It is now working, I don't quite understand my error when I first tried it, but your code worked. Appreciate the help.